# CPU usage in Apache Tomcat

Tags: webserver, tomcat

I had a query regarding Tomcat's CPU usage, I'm using it for J2EE applications. While experimenting with applications deployments on Tomcat I see that # of applications deployed is directly proportional to the CPU usage of the tomcat process. Is it fair to say that it depends upon the number of applications deployed to Tomcat's /webapps directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I couldn't find any answer to this. So I upgraded to a newer version of Tomcat and the CPU usage has returned back to normal. Either it was some settings issue or a bug.